# Payara database connection error when pinging

Tags: database, intellij-idea, jdbc, mariadb, payara

I'm trying to ping from Payara to make sure the database connection using MySQL in IntelliJ is working. I am using the following tools:

- IntelliJ Ultimate 2023.3.2
- MariaDB 10.9.1
- Payara 6
- JDK 17
- Jakarta EE 10
- I have made sure that the login credentials and database name of MySQL is the same as in Payara.
- I have added the mysql-connector JAR file to lib/ext/
  [image: The error when I try to ping]
- I added "?useSSL=false" to the database URL, but it doesn't work and it didn't work without it.
- I have tried both "MySQL" and "MySQL8" as the database vendor driver
  [image: Payara config]

When I ping, this is the complete error message I get in the server log file:

```
[2024-02-01T16:58:26.046+0100] [Payara 6.2023.12] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.org.glassfish.jdbc.util] [tid: _ThreadID=103 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1706803106046] [levelValue: 900] [[
  RAR8068: Using default datasource : __ds_jdbc_ra for pool : test]]

[2024-02-01T16:58:26.047+0100] [Payara 6.2023.12] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.org.glassfish.jdbc.util] [tid: _ThreadID=103 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1706803106047] [levelValue: 900] [[
  RAR8068: Using default datasource : __ds_jdbc_ra for pool : test]]

[2024-02-01T16:58:26.069+0100] [Payara 6.2023.12] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.gjc.util] [tid: _ThreadID=103 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1706803106069] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  RAR5099 : Wrong class name or classpath for Datasource Object 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.loadClass(CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.java:83)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at com.sun.gjc.common.DataSourceObjectBuilder.getDataSourceObject(DataSourceObjectBuilder.java:264)
    at com.sun.gjc.common.DataSourceObjectBuilder.constructDataSourceObject(DataSourceObjectBuilder.java:110)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.getDataSource(ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1376)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.getDataSource(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:178)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.getUnpooledConnection(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:618)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.testConnectionPool(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:430)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.pingConnectionPool(ConnectorRuntime.java:1174)
    at org.glassfish.connectors.admin.cli.PingConnectionPool.execute(PingConnectionPool.java:145)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:552)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:376)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:582)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:574)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:376)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:573)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1879)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1755)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateExecCommand.executeCommandLegacyFormat(TemplateExecCommand.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateCommandGetResource.processGetLegacyFormat(TemplateCommandGetResource.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor135.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:146)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:478)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:400)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:697)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:367)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
]]

[2024-02-01T16:58:26.070+0100] [Payara 6.2023.12] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service] [tid: _ThreadID=103 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1706803106070] [levelValue: 900] [[
  RAR8054: Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ test ], Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource]]

[2024-02-01T16:58:26.076+0100] [Payara 6.2023.12] [SEVERE] [] [org.glassfish.admingui] [tid: _ThreadID=167 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1706803106076] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  RestResponse.getResponse() gives FAILURE.  endpoint = 'http://localhost:4848/management/domain/resources/ping-connection-pool.json'; attrs = '{id=test}']]
```

I tried all the things I mentioned above. From what I have seen, I have the correct JAR file and the correct datasource class name and resource type. I have not seen another post which still has this problem. Does anyone have any tips what I can try or what might be the problem?

Comment: Note [10.9](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/release-notes-mariadb-10-9-series/) series is end of life. Any reason not to use [MariaDB Connector/J](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/#jdbcmysql-scheme-compatibility), which is actually tested against MariaDB, rather than mysql-connector which isn't? As its a pretty important aspect, including its version number would be good.